# Attr 'value' is changed but not being sent

Tags: jquery, sitefinity

I have page1 with a button, when the button is clicked, it takes the user to page2. The Url of page1 is being passed to Page2 as a Query String.

Page2 is a form, I am trying to grab the passed Query String and populate an input field in this form on Page2.  I'm using `.attr('value', 'new value')` to change the value of my input field.  I can see the new value (the query string) is changed when I inspect the field, everything works but when I submit the form, I get an empty field with no value in the email submission.

By the way, the form fields are created with Sitefinity form builder.

I am binding the URL of page1 to button click with this:

```
$('#btnNeedHelpQueryString').bind('click', function () {
    var url = '/contact?name=' + encodeURIComponent(eventTitle);
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

and I'm retrieving the Url on Page2 using this:

```
var queryString = new Array();
    $(function () {
        if (queryString.length == 0) {
            if (window.location.search.split('?').length > 1) {
                var params = window.location.search.split('?')[1].split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                    var key = params[i].split('=')[0];
                    var value = decodeURIComponent(params[i].split('=')[1]);
                    queryString[key] = value;
                }
            }
        }
        if (queryString["name"] != null) {
            var data = queryString["name"];
            $('#MainContentWrapper_C001_ctl00_ctl00_formControls').find('.populatedField input.sfTxt').attr("value", data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does the input have an attribute `name`? Provide relevant code in question itself to replicate issue

Comment: It does. Sitefinity generates some weird names for input fields.

Comment: why not trying this .val("new value")

Comment: .val() doesn't even create the value="" attribute in the DOM let alone populating the field with the new value.

Comment: If you type this `$('#MainContentWrapper_C001_ctl00_ctl00_formControls').find('.populatedField input.sfTxt').length` into the browser's console, does it return anything? I'm able to set the value of a form builder textbox using both the `.attr('value', data)` and `.val(data)` methods

Comment: The console returns 1.  I can see the value is populated in the DOM when I inspect the code but the field is still empty and when I submit the form, the field returns empty.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I created a test 'Page1' and 'Page2' (with a form with 1 textbox) on my Sitefinity site and used your javascript. I was able to get the value populated in the DOM and in the form responses in the backend. Sorry I can't be more help!

Comment: chris, thanks for your comment.. It is certainly strange but I think I found a clue.  It works when I load the jQuery at the bottom of the page but it doesn't work with the jQuery the is already loaded in the header of the site in the Master template. I definitely don't want to load two versions of jQuery though.

Comment: Ah interesting. If I set the page's javascript to be loaded in the <head> tag, then I get an error (because it gets inserted in the <head> before jquery is loaded -- which is set to be inserted in the <head> tag in our page template). So maybe if you can set your page's javascript to be loaded before the closing body tag? (Although not sure of your script locations/templates)